# How to fix wordpress slow first time load (Local Server)?

Tags: performance, server

**Summary**

Accessing WordPress page for the first time took about 5-7s to load from a local server vs 300-500ms for subsequent page loads on any links. Approximately 10x slower for first time access which is unacceptable. Browser cache is disabled in developer tools. How to fix?

**Long Info**

I noticed that whenever I access a wordpress page for the first time (like cleared everything in chrome) that page I am accessing took about 5-7s to load considering that this is a local server, that load time is unacceptable. However, after that first time load, subsequent page access just took only about 0.3-0.5s or 300-500ms (still long for local server but order of magnitude faster than the first time load). To eliminate the cache issue, I disabled it from browser developer tools, so all page requests, regardless of first time or subsequent, accesses web files directly from the server.

**Test done so far**

At first I though It was a server Issue, and then I transferred to localhost to see if the problem persist. And indeed it does.

I also though that it might be A DNS issue, so I checked the httpd.conf and windows DNS host files, I got 1 and only IP there, which is 127.0.0.1. I also updated the host in wordpress config.php to 127.0.0.1 as well as from the data base. Still, I get the same slowness for first time load. I argued that, if this is DNS issue then, its either the page would not load OR it loads but it should be consistently be the similar. However, the slowness is only affecting the first time load.

Server restarts, full shutdown+boot does not have an influence on page loads. Its only a matter of either its first time access by client or not.

I came through a post about [nginx & php-fpm very slow on first access](https://serverfault.com/questions/576392/nginx-php-fpm-very-slow-on-first-access), where the user initially blamed his server, but It turned out, it was his CMS. And based from what I have experience, wordpress might be the cause of slow first time page load, However, I dont know which part in wordpress that I got to deal with to fix the issue, can somebody help me fix wordpress slow fist time load (on Local Server)?

**Server**

WAMP (localhost), 32 xeon core 2.7Ghz, 24Gb RAM, SATAIII HDD, OpCache Enable though Zend Engine

**Wordpress**

No Plugin, v. 4.9

**Client**

Chrome & Firefox Cache disabled in Developer Tools, cUrl

Comment: Have you checked MySQL's query cache? Do you Have an extremely large wp_options table?

Comment: .its not big, just 4 posts, but I think it was disabled by default https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/

Comment: wp_options, not wp_posts, should heavily profit from query cache, but with such a small site, it sounds unlikely that WP has accumulated a lot there. Can you trigger the behavior by restarting php-fpm/nginx/mysql?

Comment: Restarting/Shutting down the server did not trigger the issue, I also cleared opcache, before restarting/Shutting down server. I find that page loads for 0.3s only, so I guess, my server is always primed to serve files even on fresh restart/Shutting down + boot.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using curl? Does the access log for apache show any additional requests?

Comment: Hi, ok I restarted both client and server. Only new client access to the site can trigger the issue. Checked the apache access log and nothing was in there, its empty. I can try to use curl but I dont know how to use it for this issue? Can I request some curl commands?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72536/discussion-between-janh-and-dominic-guana).

Comment: I think I might have found the culprit. Every time this happens, I noticed that wp-cron launches, I disabled that for now, and still testing.

Answer (score 2):

Well website (Wordpress) page speed and load depends on many things.

1. MySql Queries
2. Image optimisation
3. Css files (more cs files more page load and page speed time).
4. Javascript files ( more js files more page load and page speed time).
5. Defer parsing of JavaScript
6. Minify JavaScript
7. Minify CSS
8. Enable gzip compression
9. Leverage browser caching
10. Minimize request size
    And much more.

Test your website with https://gtmetrix.com and start fixing issues as the websites presents to you. For this you will need to put your local server online with ip.

Page speed and page load need a lot of attention and it is a process not a single issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. Based on the current testing I made it seems, the problem is wordpress php. I rebuilded the site using the same server but I used my own php codes. Now, it can load in just 34-170ms for the full featured site vs 300ms - 500ms for wordpress in localhost.